# Magnetic flux in a loop from a circular coil

Tags: magnetic-fields, gauss-law, magnetostatics

### **Problem**

> At the center of a circular coil with length $L$, radius $b$ and $N$ windings is there a small circular ring with radius $a << b$. The ring is coaxial with the axis of the circular coil. We want to find the magnetix flux through the small coil if the current in the coil is $I$.

**Attempt**

In order to solve this problem, I thought that we might think of each winding in the coil as a circular loop. The magnetic field from a circular loop is given by:

$$ \vec{B} = \frac{\mu_0Ib^2}{2(z^2+b^2)^{3/2}} \hat{z}$$

where $b$ is the radius of the ring and $z$ is the distance to our field point.

If we think of each winding as a circular loop with thickness $dz$, the current $I$ is therefore replaced by $I/L dz$. Meaning:

$$ d\vec{B} = \frac{\mu_0I/Lb^2}{2L (z^2+b^2)^{3/2}} dz \hat{z} $$

Integrating this from $-l/2$ to $l/2$ since the small loop is in the center of the coil, we get:

$$\vec{B} = \frac{\mu_0I}{(L^2+4b^2)^{1/2}} \hat{z} $$

The flux through the loop is then $\Phi = B \cdot \pi a^2$. However, according to the answer sheet of mine, I'm missing a factor of $N$. It feels like this is the wrong way of solving the problem, but it's the closest I can get to the actual answer.

How can I strategically divide the problem into small parts where I calculate the contribution of the flux from each "ring", to get the final answer. Or is there any other more efficient way of solving it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your small mistake is in the expression of the surface current:$$j_S=\frac{NI}{L}$$The missing factor $N$ in your expression explains the missing $N$ factor in the final expression. Apart from that, your method is perfectly valid.

Comment: Btw if you’re essentially calculating a mutual inductance coefficient. Another method would be to invoke the symmetry of the mutual induction and calculating the flux of the ring’s field through the coil. In this case, use the potential vector of an ideal vector and integrate over the each circles composing the coil. You’ll get exactly the same result. Efficiency depends on whether you are more familiar with the magnetic field of a ring or the vector potential of a dipole.

Comment: @lpz Thank you for your comment. However, I still can't get why we multiple by $N$ though in that expression since it feels like I'm already considering all the windings when I do my integration from $-L/2$ to $L/2$.

Comment: Intuitively, your result does not depend on $N$ so it is necessarily false. As usual for windings, you typically replace the current $I$ by the effective current $NI$. This is why you do windings in the first place, you increase current from a magnetic point of view without having to increase the amps circulating through your circuit.

Comment: @lpz Oh ok, I think I got it now :) Thank you for your help!